When calling self.boot.register_next_step_handler(asdas, Bsu_func.calc_info) The code does not expect a response from the user
I commented out the problem place, the problem is that when self.bot.register_next_step_handler is triggered, the code does not wait for a response from the user and therefore a message is not passed to the calc_info function and an error occurs:
How to make the cat wait for working out self.bot.register_next_step_handler
class Bzu_func:
    def __init__(self, bot):
            self.state = 'kalories'
            self.all_calories = 0
            self.protein = 0
            self.writen_calories = 0
            self.bot = bot

    def calc_info(self, message):
        message_kall_info = message.text
        if message_kall_info.isdigit() == True:
            if self.state == 'kalories':
                self.state = "protein"
                self.writen_calories = int(message_kall_info)
                self.all_calories += self.writen_calories
                self.state = 'protein'
    
                asdas = self.bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Напишите количество белка")
                self.bot.register_next_step_handler(asdas, Bzu_func.calc_info) # PROBLEM HERE!!!!!!
            elif self.state == 'protein':
                self.state = "kalories"
                count_protein = int(message_kall_info)
                self.protein += count_protein
                self.bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "белки записаны")
    
                BotDB.add_bzu_info(message.from_user.id, self.protein, self.all_calories)
    
                user_bzu_info = BotDB.get_bzu_info(message.from_user.id)
                self.bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Количество калории: {user_bzu_info[1]}, Количество белка: {user_bzu_info[0]}")
        else:
            self.state = "none"
            self.bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Вы ввели не цифрууууууууууууууууууууууу

`
